# Device disappears from ADB devices when entering sideload

Tags: twrp, side-loading, oneplus-one

I'm installing a rom on my Oneplus One, so I go in TWRP, wipe, plug in my phone and use ADB devices. The device lists as usually. When I enter sideload in TWRP though, my phone disappears from the devices, so I can't sideload a rom.

TWRP version 2.8.5.1
ADB version 1.0.32

Comment: Seems to be a driver issue

Comment: I have the same problem with cwm.