# TWRP: adb devices works in recovery but fails in sideload mode

Tags: twrp, lineageos, side-loading

I want to install a custom rom (LineageOS with microG) on My Asus Zenfone Max Pro M1. I followed every steps detailed in the tutorial (enable debugging, unlock bootloader, run fastboot, flash TWRP, reboot in recovery,  backup then wipe the system with TWRP).

My problem is when I want to sideload the custom rom. So, `adb devices` works and detects my phone in recovery mode. However, as soon as I lauch the sideload mode in TWRP, `adb devices` is not able to detect my phone anymore and the command `adb sideload xxxxxx.zip` fails because it cannot see any device.

I'm running TWRP 3.2.3, my computer runs on GNU/Linux (Xubuntu 18.04), I have the latest version of the Android SDK.

It is the same question as here from 2015: [Device disappears from ADB devices when entering sideload](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/102698) but there was no answer.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you install the ROM directly from TWRP?

Comment: That's indeed what I ended up doing

Answer (score 9):

Eventually, I found a workaround (which is not a fix but it allowed me to continue the installation).

Since my device was detected in discovery, I did not used sideload. I just pushed the image to the sdcard with:

```
adb push xxxxx.zip /sdcard/
```

and then I installed the image from the sdcard directly in TWRP.

Answer (score 1):

I have this issue when the adb server is running without root permissions. Try:

```
$ killall adb
$ sudo adb devices
```

This will run the adb server with the correct permissions, then you'll be able to sideload.

Comment: See https://www.reddit.com/r/LineageOS/comments/cez05b/twrp_adb_sideloading_fails_device_has_no/.

Comment: Still fails with me. Even with root, 'adb devices' works outside of sideload but not during sideload.